# What features does D3D have that OpenGL does not (and vice versa)?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx11

Are there any feature comparisons on Direct3D 11 and the newest OpenGL versions?

Well, simply put, Direct3D 11 introduced three main features (taken from Wikipedia):

- Tessellation
- Multithreaded rendering
- Compute shaders
- Increased texture cache

Now I'm wondering, how does the newest versions of OpenGL cope with these features? And since I have this feeling that there are features that Direct3D lacks from OpenGL's side, what are those?

Comment: Since "OGL vs D3D" is somewhat of a holy war topic, I'm going to ask this:  What problem are you trying to solve with this information?

Comment: @Tetrad, wanted to know about tesselation in OGL.

Comment: wouldn't have been better to ask something more specific then, like "what hardware tessellation options a la DX11 exist for OpenGL"?

Comment: @Tetrad, but if later on I'm interested in Multithreaded rendering and Compute Shaders? I better ask one global question, than 10 specific ones. But if in any way, that's against the "rules", I can correct myself in the future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When one talks about OpenGL and D3D "features," one could be referring to either:

1. the feature sets supported by hardware that the graphics API exposes, or
2. the feature sets of the API itself that don't really relate to the hardware.

For example, a programmable tessellation pipeline is something the hardware generally has to support (let's ignore, for the purposes of practicality, that an API could in theory implement missing hardware features in software as that's generally too slow to be of real use). Presupposing it does, you can gain access to that pipeline in both D3D and OpenGL. D3D builds the interfaces for doing so into the core API of D3D11 via the [hull/domain shaders and tessellation APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). OpenGL provided [an extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/tessellation_shader.txt) that was eventually promoted to part of the core API. When it comes to hardware features, OpenGL and Direct3D are generally equivalent in terms of what you can make the hardware do via either API. The differences come in how.

There are hundreds of small API features (unrelated to actual hardware capability) that differ in both APIs. It's not practical to list them all in an answer. Aside from the fact that D3D is a "traditionally COM-like" API and OpenGL is a "traditionally C-like" API, one of the biggest differences in the feature set is that OpenGL has its rich extension mechanism (and D3D has no such thing). This tends to mean that OpenGL is in theory more flexible and adaptable to new capabilities, at the cost of being slightly more cumbersome to use (thus the plethora of OpenGL extension assistance APIs like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: -1: "OpenGL provides an extension." That extension is *core OpenGL* in 4.0. And since any hardware that could implement that extension could implement the rest of 4.0... not many use it as an extension. And even then, using it as an extension doesn't change the code, because the tessellation extension is a [core extension](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Extension#Core_Extensions). The functions and enums don't have an "ARB" suffix. So code that uses it as an extension looks the same as regular core GL code.

Comment: Fair point, I edited my answer slightly to reflect that.

Comment: It was not "eventually promoted" to anything; ARB_tesselation_shader was released on the *same day* as GL 4.0. If anything, it was the core functionality that was spun off into an extension form. The ARB simply does that these days as a matter of course.

Comment: I think the confusion here stems from the more primitive ATI tesselation extension (which was actually something completely different), with perhaps a mixture of GLU tesselation (which didn't even run in hardware) thrown in?

Answer (score 7):

Taken from Wikipedia, too: there aren't [many differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_OpenGL_and_Direct3D). Strictly speaking, OpenGL is usually slightly behind Direct3D in terms of features, because the standardisation takes time. However, many of these features are available as OpenGL vendor-specific extensions first, then in the standard itself after some time.

- Compute shaders are available in GLSL shader model 5.
- Tessellation is available in OpenGL 4.x (see a [tutorial here](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=48)).
- Multithreaded rendering is tricky in OpenGL, but [certainly possible](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading), and in all honesty I believe most of what D3D does is manage a big global lock and the interaction with the GPU is still single-threaded.
- I don't know exactly what's implied by "Increased texture cache" but I believe they just raised the lowest common denominator for that feature.

As for your last question, in my opinion, the features that Direct3D lacks the more are a Mac OS X version, a Linux version, an Android version, an iPad/iPhone version, and a PlayStation 3 version :-) (while the last three platforms actually support OpenGL ES rather than OpenGL, it makes porting software a lot easier than porting Direct3D to OpenGL ES)

Comment: That last list took me by suprise, haha.

Comment: D3D has more sensible management of multiple monitors/multiple gfx cards too; can't be underestimated with some end-users.

Comment: OpenGL lacks an Android/iPad/iPhone/PS3 version too. OpenGL ES is *not* the same as desktop OpenGL. They are *similar*, but there are some incompatibilities.

Comment: Well, well, you're right. I was trying to end in a humorous tone, but I agree it may be misleading. I'll clarify what I meant.

Comment: @NicolBolas But what if one wrote it all in 'OpenGL ES' which is fully compatible with OpenGL 4.1, which is then indeed OpenGL? :D

Comment: @DMan: Except that GL ES is *not* "fully compatible" with Desktop GL 4.1. Certainly not with core OpenGL; ES shaders wouldn't compile under core 4.1 rules.

Comment: @NicolBolas: does the nitpicking serve any useful purpose? You are making it look like GL and GL ES are irreconcilably incompatible while, honestly, they're 99% the same thing. ES shaders compile with extremely minor tuning, often no more than `#if GL_ES` around the precision specifiers.

Comment: @SamHocevar: It's not nitpicking; it's accurate information. It doesn't matter that they're "close", because you still have to expend effort to make the same shaders run on both. Not as much as if you were doing D3D/GL ES of course. But the statement that "'OpenGL ES' which is fully compatible with OpenGL 4.1" is wrong, and imparting wrong information is not what this website should be about. I'm sorry if you feel that correcting misinformation is nitpicking, but I disagree.

Comment: @SamHocevar: And FYI: the differences between GLSL ES and desktop GLSL aren't around precision specifiers. GLSL 1.30 and above already have those (though desktop GLSL says that they do nothing). It's more about the `attribute/varying` stuff that was replaced with `in/out`. It's more about the `layout(location=x)` that GLSL 3.30 brings, `layout(binding=Y)` that GLSL 4.20 brings. Explicit attribute locations in shaders changes how you use them in your code; a simple `#ifdef` in your shader isn't going to cut it. Making that work requires C/C++ code changes.

Comment: @NicolBolas: explicit attribute locations are not mandatory in GLSL, so that would absolutely not prevent a GL ES shader from compiling on a GL platform. Same for `attribute/varying` which were deprecated but not removed. All the details you are mentioning here are real differences, and you choose to view them as defining two different standards. Fair enough. I choose to view them as variants of the same thing, because given how OpenGL changes between major versions, you might as well say that OpenGL is not the same as OpenGL.

Comment: @SamHocevar: "explicit attribute locations are not mandatory in GLSL" They most certainly are for GLSL version 3.30 and above. And `attribute/varying` are *removed* in the GLSL 1.50+ core profile. You cannot talk about GLSL like it is one language; it has many versions, and each version has its own requirements and features. The only way to make GLSL ES and desktop GLSL work is to ignore everything that changed with desktop since 1.20 and to use the compatibility profile. Which Mac OSX Lion doesn't even support in its 3.2 mode.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I'm all for being proven wrong and improve my knowledge and everything, but I really don't understand where the standards state all that. If the [GL 4.1 quick ref](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl41-quick-reference-card.pdf) states that `attribute/varying` are _deprecated but not removed_ from the core profile, how could they have been removed from 1.50? About explicit attribute locations, section 4.3.8 of [GL 3.30](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.3.30.6.pdf) says where layout qualifiers _can_ appear, but never where they _must_ appear.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers (Sam and Josh) cover most of what you need to know, but just adding a few extra points.

Before that however, Josh's point about the API not offering features is worth repeating.  It's quite incorrect to say things like "OpenGL has vertex buffers" or "D3D has shaders", and was just as incorrect back in the day when you used to read things like "D3D doesn't have a stencil buffer" or "OpenGL has polygon offset".  Your gfx hardware has features and the API exposes them; if your gfx card doesn't have a feature no amount of exposition in the API will give you it (unless you use some form of software emulation, which you really don't want to do) and if your gfx card has a feature but the API doesn't support it then you can't use it either.

Moving on with the extra stuff.

D3D has more sensible management of multiple monitors/multiple gfx cards, which can't be underestimated with some end-users.

Explicit memory pools in D3D9 or below were nice (aside from the dreaded D3DERR_DEVICELOST) and it's vertex buffer API is much cleaner and clearer and easier to use.  Separation of layout specification from data specification was the right decision IMO.  GL has improved with attrib arrays and VAOs but it's still not all the way there.

D3D also guarantees a single consistent shader compiler for all users and on all hardware, whereas each GL implementation has a different shader compiler.  The Effects framework is also very nice.

D3D generally has better quality drivers than OpenGL.  That's pretty critical.

OpenGL has extensions.  That's something of a double-edged sword, as while you can get access to newer vendor-specific features earlier, you may end up with a mess of multiple codepaths all doing broadly the same thing.  You make your own choice about which side of that tradeoff you're happier to accept.

OpenGL still has some nice things that D3D is missing.  The accumulation buffer (on hardware that accelerates it) can do some neat things; D3D11.1 is apparrently finally going to get logic ops on the framebuffer.

glCopyTexSubImage is very nice in cases where it's implemented properly (which should be everywhere as Doom 3 used it) and D3D has no direct equivalent, to pull another specific example out.

OpenGL is capable of providing software fallback for things required by the spec but unsupported in hardware (not all things however) whereas D3D will normally give you a big ugly crash or error.  Another tradeoff where you decide (although I still have nasty memories of a Geforce FX - which supported NP2 textures as required by the GL 2.0 spec - going back to full software emulation without warning if you actually tried to *use* one...)

OpenGL tends to maintain backwards compatibility through revisions of the API (I'm ignoring core contexts here) whereas D3D does not.  There are arguments for and against each philosophy that it's probably not appropriate to retread here; just something to be aware of.

OpenGL still has bind-to-modify whereas D3D does not; you operate directly on the object (or pass it as a param) instead.  The OpenGL way tends to mess up any state filtering you might be doing, IMO.

They're the main big ones I can think of right now; nothing too earth-shattering but enough to tip a decision.

Finally, it's also incorrect to state that Android, mobile devices, the PS3, etc use OpenGL, because they actually don't.  They use GL ES which is in some ways a subset of full OpenGL and in other ways quite different (and on the PS3 anyone concerned about performance uses libgcm anyway).

Comment: "D3D also guarantees a single consistent shader compiler for all users and on all hardware, whereas each GL implementation has a different shader compiler." Not entirely true. Only the front-end of the shader compiler is consistent. It compiles to an intermediate form, which the internal driver's compiler compiles to a final form. While that's still a big improvement over the GL situation (minimizing front-end incompatibilities), it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Fair point; conceded.

Comment: I disagree with what the libgcm comment seems to imply, for the simple reason that PGSL and libgcm are certainly not mutually exclusive. But it’s hard to argue about the specifics or even about usage statistics when so much must be kept secret…

Comment: I probably should have mentioned something about tools and documentation too...